# Hold flow control inside function until it's complete all task: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have requirement to store the returned value from Promise to global variable, I am trying with following way-

```
this.getData().then(data => {
     this.gloabalData = data;       
});
// Doing Operation with globalData
```

But problem is that before updating the value of globalData with data, it's taking the default value of globalData. It's means before processing the getData operation, control comes down and using the previous value of globalData. So, Is there any way to hold the control inside getData function before it's complete all task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just not possible.

When

```
// Doing Operation with globalData
```

is reached there is no `data` available yet

```
data => {
 this.gloabalData = data;
}
```

is a function you pass to `then()` to be called when `getData()` completes with a result.

```
// Doing Operation with globalData
```

is executed loooooong (in case of a server call) before `getData()` completes.

Just do

```
this.getData().then(data => {
     this.gloabalData = data;       
     // Doing Operation with globalData
});
```

or

```
this.getData().then(data => {
     this.gloabalData = data;       
}).then(data => {
// Doing Operation with globalData
});
```

Comment: thnx for answer, I know, I can do like that but I've requirement to access the globalData outside.

Comment: The just add a return before `this.getData()` and do the `.then(data => ...)` part there.

Comment: Can I store returned value into globalData variable?

Comment: Sure, but this won't help you. It's not about **where**, it's about **when**, and **when** `// Doing Operation with globalData` is executed in the example of your question `data => { this.gloabalData = data; }` has not yet been called. If you make async calls you always have to chain calls that depend on the result of the async call with `.map()` (or similar operators for Observable`) and `.then()` for `Promise`. There is absolutely nothing you can do about it.